# How to replace FileObserver in Android 10?

Tags: android, android-10.0, storage-access-framework, fileobserver

`android.os.FileObserver` requires a `java.io.File` to function.
But with Android 10 Google restricted access to everything but your app's private directory due to the famous "Storage Access Framework". Thus, accessing anything via `java.io.File` breaks and renders `FileObserver` useless unless you intend to use it in your app's private directory. However, I want to be notified when something is changed in a certain directory on external storage. I would also like to avoid periodically checking for changes.

I tried using `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(uri,notifyForDescendants,observer)` and ran into some problems with that method:

- Every `Uri` I have plugged in so far was accepted
- It neither fails nor notifies if the `Uri` doesn't work
- I cannot find any documentation telling me which `Uri`s actually work

The only thing I got working to some extent is the following approach:

```kotlin
// works, but returns all changes to the external storage
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), true, contentObserver)
```

Unfortunately this includes all of the external storage and only returns Media `Uri`s when changes happen - for example `content://media/external/file/67226`.

**Is there a way to find out whether or not that `Uri` points to my directory?**

**Or is there a way to make `registerContentObserver()` work with a `Uri` in such a way that I get a notification whenever something in the folder has changed?**

I also had no success trying various Uris related to `DocumentsFile` and external storage `Uri`s.

Comment: maybe try passing the directory uri instead of External Conten Uri.

Comment: I should have mentioned but that didn't work.

Comment: @squaresandcircles were you able to resolve the issue. I am working on similar task and stuck on this.

Comment: @squaresandcircles did you resolved this issue? i'm getting stuck on it

Comment: Problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting errors when even trying to use the base constructor such as the following -

```
No direct method <init>(Ljava/util/List;I)V in class Landroid/os/FileObserver; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.os.FileObserver' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
```

From a comment on [Detect file change using FileObserver on Android](https://gist.github.com/shirou/659180):

> I saw that message (or something like that) when i was trying to use constructor FileObserver(File).  Use of **deprecated** FileObserver(String) solved my problem....  Original FileObserver has bugs.

Full disclosure, I was using the Xamarin.Android API; however, the gist and the commenter I quoted were both working with Java.  At any rate, indeed - tried again using the counterpart `String` constructor and I was finally able to make and use the observer.  Grinds my gears to use a deprecated API, but apparently they're hanging onto it at least up to and including [Android 12.0.0_r3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-12.0.0_r3/core/java/android/os/FileObserver.java)...  still, would much prefer the supported constructors actually work.  Maybe there's some warrant here for filing an issue.

Comment: The counterpart String constructor works for me too.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to implement FileObserver on Android 10 with `ContentObserver`, but it might only work with media files since it works with media content uris.

The uri for `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver()` should be the file's corresponding media uri (e.g. `content://media/external/file/49`) which is queried by file path.

```
fun getMediaUri(context: Context, file: File): Uri? {
    val externalUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
    context.contentResolver.query(
        externalUri,
        null,
        "${MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA} = ?",
        arrayOf(file.path),
        null
    )?.use { cursor ->
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")
            val id = cursor.getLong(idIndex)
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(externalUri, "$id")
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Then `ContentObserver.onChange()` will be triggered for every file change with `uri: content://media/external/file/{id}`; `uri` in `ContentObserver.onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)` will always be `content://media/external/file`; only registered file will be with id (e.g. `content://media/external/file/49?deletedata=false`).

Does what `FileObserver` used to do when input uri's path matches registered uri.

Answer (score -2):

I have a temporary solution for this issue, so let's see if this can help.
I start an infinite `while` loop watching for file created and file deleted (if you want file modified or file renamed you have to implement more) using `DocumentFile`. Below is my sample:

```
private static int currentFileIndirectory = 0;
private static final int FILE_CREATED = 0;
private static final int FILE_DELETED = 1;

private static DocumentFile[] onDirectoryChanged(DocumentFile[] documentFiles, int event) {
    Log.d("FileUtil", "onDirectoryChanged: " + event);
    if (event == FILE_CREATED) {
    } else {

    }
    return documentFiles;
}

private static boolean didStartWatching = false;

private static void startWatchingDirectory(final DocumentFile directory) {
    if (!didStartWatching) {
        didStartWatching = true;
        DocumentFile[] documentFiles = directory.listFiles();
        if (null != documentFiles && documentFiles.length > 0) {
            currentFileIndirectory = documentFiles.length;
        }

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    DocumentFile[] documentFiles = directory.listFiles();
                    if (null != documentFiles && documentFiles.length > 0) {
                        if (documentFiles.length != currentFileIndirectory) {
                            if (documentFiles.length > currentFileIndirectory) {//file created
                                DocumentFile[] newFiles = new DocumentFile[documentFiles.length - currentFileIndirectory];
                                onDirectoryChanged(newFiles, FILE_CREATED);
                            } else {//file Deleted
                                onDirectoryChanged(null, FILE_DELETED);
                            }
                            currentFileIndirectory = documentFiles.length;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a poor implementation - it introduces a strenuously polling loop, and does not actually provide the `onDirectoryChanged` callback any of the new files, just an empty array sized to the number of new files.  Might as well change the `documentFiles` parameter to an `int`.